# How to add Barlegend in ListPlot as z axis?

Tags: plotting, legending

I have data in the form of
x={1,3,5,6,2,4,6,4.5,2.5,2.1,5.7}; y={3,6,2,1,8,4,3,9,11,16,9}; z={0.001,0.004,0.012,0.005,0.002,0.003,0.018,0.09,0.007,0.005,0.009};

Data={1, 3, 0.001}, {3, 6, 0.004}, {5, 2, 0.012}, {6, 1, 0.005}, {2, 8, 0.002}, {4, 4, 0.003}, {6, 3, 0.018}, {4.5, 9, 0.09}, {2.5, 11, 0.007}, {2.1, 16, 0.005}, {5.7, 9, 0.009};

I want to plot the 'x' and 'y' axis in ListPlot(Plotstyle->Dot) and want to add the z-axis as a bar legend against each corresponding value of 'XY'.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Data = Sort[{{1, 3, 0.001}, {3, 6, 0.004}, {5, 2, 0.012}, {6, 1, 
     0.005}, {2, 8, 0.002}, {4, 4, 0.003}, {6, 3, 0.018}, {4.5, 9, 
     0.009}, {2.5, 11, 0.007}, {2.1, 16, 0.005}, {5.7, 9, 0.009}}];


colorBar[arg_] := Blend[{Red, Green, Blue}, Rescale[arg, {0, 0.012}]];
ListPlot[Most /@ Data, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction :> 
  Function[{x, y}, 
   colorBar[
    Data[[Position[Data[[All, 1]], 
        Nearest[Data[[All, 1]], x][[1]]][[1, 1]], 3]]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{{Red, Green, Blue}, {0, 0.012}}, 
   LegendLayout -> "Column", Charting`TickSide -> Right, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, Black}, LegendMarkerSize -> 200, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True, LegendLabel -> "Z"], Frame -> True]
```

[image]